# Need help for the category posts layout in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

On my wordpress website, I am using NewsCard theme referring [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5A1D3AyMDsY&t=2774s).

I have added categories to Menu but I am running into a strange problem.

**As visible in the below image, I am getting huge gutters between the news cards which is ugly and resulting into the cards layout as very long vertical post cards.**

Can someone help me resolving this? I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong here. I was using  generatepress theme earlier.

[image]

The more natural layout should be:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a link to the page or share the html code, don't know how to help you without it!

Comment: Here is the page -     https://examtipsindia.com/technology/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file https://examtipsindia.com/wp-content/plugins/gp-premium/blog/functions/css/style.min.css?ver=1.12.2 this rule is adding the issue

```
.generate-columns.grid-50, .grid-sizer.grid-50 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

I can't see without accessing your admin the best way to add a custom CSS rule to fix the one above, but as I don't see a child theme or plugin, go to Appearance > Cutomize > Additional CSS, add the CSS below and "Publish" to save the changes:

```
body.archive.category #main .generate-columns.grid-50{
    width:auto;
}
```

That should do it, but if it doesn't let me know.

Comment: Thanks @Tami, it worked. But my intention was to fix the wordpress layout which I guess was broken with my earlier experiment with the generatepress theme. But for now, your fix is perfect. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helped. I wouldn't say something was broken. It was more of a css styling conflict between your theme and the gp-premium plugin not playing nicely together. WordPress itself had nothing to do there!